# Filter away specific rows from php mysql fetch array result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an sql table as below

```
+---+-------+-----+   
|Sl | Name  |Value|   
+---+-------+-----+   
| 1 | Name1 | 1   | 
| 2 | Name2 | 2   |
| 3 | Name3 | 2   |  
| 4 | Name4 | 3   |
| 5 | Name5 | 4   |
+---+-------+-----+
```

I have a php query `$query3 = "select * from table";`

The query returns all rows and my required columns. But I want to exclude rows which has value 2 in the column "Value", like this;

```
+---+-------+-----+   
|Sl | Name  |Value|   
+---+-------+-----+   
| 1 | Name1 | 1   |  
| 4 | Name4 | 3   |
| 5 | Name5 | 4   |
+---+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `Sl`, `Name`, `Value` from `table` WHERE `Value` != 2
```